# Using the Google Analytics PHP Client Library in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel and am trying to integrate the Google Analytics PHP Client Library (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php) in an application I am building.

According to the documentation , the library needs to be installed via Composer and then loaded using:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

In the vendors folder, I can see that there is a folder named google. So my question is, what would be the correct way to load this library in Laravel? Would it be using the code shown above, or some other method?

Thanks

Comment: You need to execute this in cmd `$ composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thanks @AyazShah, after I do that will the library be loaded automatically or does anything else need to be done?

Answer (score 2):

The autoload.php file is already required by your laravel app, you should be able to access it by it's namespace after running `composer dump-autoload` as suggested by Ayaz.

You may want to look at a package like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics where they've done the work to integrate the google analytics api into Laravel a bit more.  Even if you don't use it I'm sure you can glean some good info from checking out the source files.

Comment: Thanks @wheelmaker. How do I go about finding what its namespace is? Is it listed somewhere?

Comment: They should follow ps-4 naming conventions but you can just open the source files and check them out, namespace declarations are always at the top.

Comment: I'm currently using this package it was flawless and works properly.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the documentation , the library needs to be installed via Composer and then loaded

You can do it by executing following command in your git bash or cmd

`$ composer dump-autoload`